# javascript SWITCH statement not triggering

Tags: javascript

I have a `switch` statement in my javascript on an ASP.NET C# web application. I am debugging it with FireBug and it is erroring out: as soon as it reaches the `switch` it exists it immediately.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {

    $('#received_dateTextbox').mask("99/99/99");
    $('#report_dateTextBox').mask("99/99/99");
    $('#occurrence_dateTextBox').mask("99/99/99");

    //var checkValues='';

    $('table input:checkbox').click(function() {

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var checkText = $(this).next('a').text();
            var hrefValue = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
            var trimIndex = hrefValue.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
            var checkValue =  hrefValue.substr(trimIndex, hrefValue.indexOf("')",trimIndex)-trimIndex);

            //checkValues+=checkValue+";";

            switch(checkValue)
            {
                //preanalytical other
                case "21": 
                    var userInput = prompt("Other:", "Other:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Other:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical other
                case "53": 
                    var userInput = prompt("Other:", "Other:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Other:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //postanalytical other
                case "89": 
                    var userInput = prompt("Other:", "Other:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Other:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //other other
                case "95": 
                    var userInput = prompt("Other:", "Other:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Other:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical liquid handler instrument failure
                case "40":
                    var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler#:", "Liquid Handler#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Liquid Handler#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical olympus instrument failure
                case "41":                   
                    var userInput = prompt("Olympus#:", "Olympus#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Olympus#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical lcms instrument failure
                case "42":
                    var userInput = prompt("LC-MS/MS#:", "LC-MS/MS#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('LC-MS/MS#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical liquid handler delay prod
                case "49":
                    var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler#:", "Liquid Handler#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Liquid Handler#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical olympus delay prod
                case "50":
                     var userInput = prompt("Olympus#:", "Olympus#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Olympus#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //analytical lcms delay prod
                case "51":
                    var userInput = prompt("LC-MS/MS#:", "LC-MS/MS#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('LC-MS/MS#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                    checkValues+=checkValue+":"+userInput;
                break;

                //wrong practice code
                case "63":
                    if (confirm("Do you want to check Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician?"))
                    { var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1n82CheckBox");
                        $(elNode).prop("checked", true);
                     }
                    else
                    { var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1n81CheckBox");
                        $(elNode).prop("checked", false);
                    }

                break;  

                default: 
                    alert('no match');                
            }
        }
    });
    //document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = checkValues;
});
```

The debugger showed me that `checkValue` definitely has a value

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No errors? Did you actually end the switch statement in your real code?

Comment: But does it have one of the values that you've `case`'d for? If you add `default: alert('no match');` to your switch, does the alert show up?

Comment: @marc yes it does have the values i cased for

Comment: @pimvdb yes i posted the rest of my code

Comment: If the alert shows up, then none of your `case` values matched.

Comment: @marc am i declaring the checkValue incorrectly? should it be a string instead of var?

Comment: No, but if checkvalue is "503", then your switch won't match because there's no `case 503` to trap that value.

Comment: @marc understood but it's not working for the values that it SHOULD work for, for example 95 or 63

Comment: Make sure there's no hidden spaces and whatnot in the value as well. `63<space>` will never match `63`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkValue` could be stored as a number, not a string as all the "case" check for.

Check if `case parseInt("95") : ...` works.

Also, check if your cases begin to work if you add a character to the number and then check for that:

`switch(checkValue + 'A')`

and then `case "53A": .... break;`

Comment: Did you try an `alert(checkValue);` right before the `switch()` - the values are OK?

Comment: I don't understand - checkValue is obviously a string.

Comment: Why would substr be returning a Number?

Comment: @Tom: checkvalue is not a string, it's actually a number(!).
See sample test code: http://jsfiddle.net/3MXtM/

Comment: @lttlrck: substr probably returns the string, but because that string looks like a number (i.e. all digits) JS engine might do something funky. JS isn't strongly-typed.

Comment: @Leon Your sample code is faulty; isNaN() will coerce a String to a Number if possible, it doesn't prove the primitive. The correct test is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Trmjt/1/ and it shows it is a String.

Comment: Note also that JS switch uses === so it doesn't coerce across types. So given the substr returns a string, the code as shown should work if the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact behavior, but if `checkValues` is null or undefined, I would expect it to break on that line.

Comment: it's defined above var checkValues='';

Comment: i removed that completely still same result

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `checkValue` has a space in it which you need to trim out? In your `default` - show the value of `checkValue` like so, which should make it clearer:

```
default: 
     alert('no match for "' + checkValue + '"');
```

Comment: i checked for that. it is exactly "95" or "63" etc

Comment: i just tried that. it WORKS specifically for the no matches, however if THERE IS a match, then it does not go into the "case"